# Align paragraph lines to center with decreasing length each line

Tags: html, css

Please suggest how can I align paragraph lines to a upside down pyramid structure. [I want to achieve something like this image,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auKUE.jpg)
So far, I have done

```css
.content-detail{
     height: 90px;
     width: 570px;
     margin: 0 auto;
     display: table;
}
.content-detail p{
    font-family: vollkorn-reg;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #333;
    font-weight: 400;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-detail">
                        <p>Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate cursus a sit amet mauris. Morbi versa accumsan ipsum velit. Nam nec tellus a odio tincidunt auctor a ornare odio. Sed non mauris vitae erat consequat auctor eu in elit</p>
</div>
```

Comment: wrap in spans and use `display: block;`